# Regarding countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Please help to to prove that if a collection of sets $A$ is countable, then the set of all finite intersections of members of $A$ is also countable.

I couldn't find the bijection between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$ be a countable collection. For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, note that $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable. For each $\alpha =(j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_k) \in \mathbb{N}^k$, define
$$
B_{k, \alpha} = A_{j_1}\cap A_{j_2}\cap \ldots\cap A_{j_k}
$$
and let
$$
\mathcal{B}_k := \{B_{k,\alpha} : \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^k\}
$$
Then $\mathcal{B}_k$ is countable, and the collection you are interested in is
$$
\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{B}_k
$$

Answer (score 1):

A countable union of countable collections is countable. So you just need to show that the collection of all possible intersections of $k$ sets is countable, for each $k$. For this, you can use the fact that ${\mathbb N} \times {\mathbb N} \times \cdots \times {\mathbb N}$ is countable if the product has finitely many copies of ${\mathbb N}$. If you need to show this as well, then just define the injection $f(x) = \prod_i p_i^{n_i}$ for given $x = (n_1,\ldots,n_k)$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime.